# Error in Code . my code is opening the webpage but its showing an error while sending text to the search box . i am new to python . Many Thanks

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

```
from selenium import webdriver from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

driver = webdriver.Chrome("C:\\Users\\rahuls1\\chromedriver.exe") 
driver.get('https://www.pastemagazine.com/')
elem = driver.find_element_by_id = ('master-search')
elem.send_keys('music')
elem.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)
time.sleep(5)
```

Error

```
File "C:\Users\rahuls1\Desktop\PYT\cl.py", line 9, in <module> elem.send_keys("music",) AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'send_keys'
```

Comment: elem = driver.find_element_by_id = ('master-search') is a text box of a search bar , i want to paste a value eg - music and search it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are assigning `'master-search'` to `elem`, not a web element. The correct way to use `find_element_by_id` is

```
elem = driver.find_element_by_id('master-search')
```

Answer (score 0):

Your find element method is wrong in your code.You are find element method is wrong    There are multiple locators available in the selenium which identifies element on the web.

- ID
- Name
- Link Text
- CSS Selector
- XPath

You can also try below xpath:

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@id='master-search']").send_keys("musics")
```

Please find below link which will let you know how to deal with web elements for more information.
https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/locating-elements.html